# Se colocar várias requisições web dentro de um loop while em python pode derrubar um site?

Tags: python

Bom pessoal tenho uma dúvida totalmente voltada a estudos e não para prejudicar ninguém
Se eu fizer requisições web e colocar dentro de um loop infinito pode tirar o site do ar? Exemplo do código abaixo em python

```
import requests
while True:
      r = requests.get("site")
      if(r.status_code == 200):
           print("Atacando site")
      else:
           print("Site fora do ar")
```

tipo esse código só para entenderem. e Desculpem qualquer coisa

Comment: `print("Atacando site")`... realmente, parece ser só para estudos.. hahahha

Answer (score -2):

É possível. Porem geralmente a carga necessária para tirar um site do ar é muito grande para um único computador. Porem ainda é possível caso o site for mal otimizado ou funcione em uma maquina menos potente.

Comment: Irei fazer o teste no meu servidor apache